# Removing or Disabling the search tools bar (or filer row) from grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm currently using jqGrid in my project and since I'm new to this datagrid I'm taking help from [jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?%28arctic%29)

Here, I've used the sorting, adding rows, deleting rows and filtering rows. The code is as follow:

```
// initialize jqxGrid
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
                            width: 900,
                            source: dataadapter,
                            theme: theme,
            editable: true,
            height: 300,
            pageable: true,
                            sortable: true,
                            showfilterrow: true,
                            filterable: true,
            rendergridrows: function(obj)
            {
                  return obj.data;
            },
            columns: [
                  { text: 'EmployeeID', editable: false, datafield: 'EmployeeID', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'First Name', datafield: 'FirstName', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'LastName', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Title', datafield: 'Title', width: 180 },
                  { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 180 },
                  { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Country', datafield: 'Country', width: 140 }
              ]
        });
         $("#jqxgrid").on("sort", function (event) {
           // $("#events").jqxPanel('clearcontent');
            var sortinformation = event.args.sortinformation;
            var sortdirection = sortinformation.sortdirection.ascending ? "ascending" : "descending";
            if (!sortinformation.sortdirection.ascending && !sortinformation.sortdirection.descending) {
                sortdirection = "null";
            }
            var eventData = "Triggered 'sort' event <div>Column:" + sortinformation.sortcolumn + ", Direction: " + sortdirection + "</div>";
           // $('#events').jqxPanel('prepend', '<div style="margin-top: 5px;">' + eventData + '</div>');
        });
        $('#clearsortingbutton').jqxButton({ height: 25, theme: theme });
        $('#sortbackground').jqxCheckBox({checked: true, height: 25, theme: theme });
        // clear the sorting.
        $('#clearsortingbutton').click(function () {
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('removesort');
        });
        // show/hide sort background
        $('#sortbackground').on('change', function (event) {
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({ showsortcolumnbackground: event.args.checked });
        });
        $("#addrowbutton").jqxButton({ theme: theme });
        $("#deleterowbutton").jqxButton({ theme: theme });
        // create new row.
        $("#addrowbutton").click(function (){//alert("here");
            var datarow = generaterow(); //alert(datarow['EmployeeID']);
            var commit = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, datarow);
        });      
        // delete row.
        $("#deleterowbutton").click(function () {
            var selectedrowindex = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getselectedrowindex');
            var rowscount = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getdatainformation').rowscount;
            if (selectedrowindex >= 0 && selectedrowindex < rowscount) {//alert('here');
                var id = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowid', selectedrowindex);
                var commit = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('deleterow', id);
            }
        });
```

From this code, I'm getting the filter row in all the columns. But I want to remove the filter from the column EmployeeId so what should I do to remove this search tool bar from EmployeeId column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct setting which you have to set to a column is "filterable: false"

Answer (score 0):

Add `search: false` to the column definitions of each column you'd like to disable the filtering.

```
            columns: [
              { text: 'EmployeeID', editable: false, datafield: 'EmployeeID', width: 100, search: false },
              { text: 'First Name', datafield: 'FirstName', width: 100 },
              { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'LastName', width: 100 },
              { text: 'Title', datafield: 'Title', width: 180 },
              { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 180 },
              { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 100 },
              { text: 'Country', datafield: 'Country', width: 140 }
          ]
```